# every gestures in touchpad is working except two fingers scrolling? (windows 10)

Tags: touchpad

My touchpad is working fine except for two fingers scrolling. Three and four fingers scrolling gesture are also fine.

The two fingers scrolling is only working in start menu, windows setting and every windows apps. other application like chrome, windows explorer, etc is not working

I've done updating touchpad driver, changing the pointer, and every guide in the internet but none of them worked.

My laptop is acer swift 3 SF314-54.
This scrolling gesture is very necessary to have for me so please help.

Note: The two fingers scrolling is working in windows 10 start menu, and every windows 10 application. But not working in other applications such as windows explorer, chrome, and every third-party applications.

Comment: What is your Windows version and that of your anti-virus? (Please start a comment with the moniker of the person you are addressing like `@harrymc`.)

Comment: @harrymc my windows is windows 10 version 1803 for x64 based system (kb4467702). i use avira for the antivirus

Comment: Try to disable avira. What make is the touchpad and which driver is installed?

Comment: @harrymc the driver is elan touchpad. I already tried installing synaptic but nothing happen in the device manager. The driver is still elan touchpad

Comment: @harrymc I did turn off avira but still not working

Comment: Try to uninstall the ELAN driver and let Windows install its own driver: In Device Manager, right-click the touchpad, select Uninstall, in the pop-up check “Delete the driver software for this device” and press OK, finally reboot.

Comment: @harrymc still doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

You might try to install the Microsoft Precision Touchpad drivers.
These are made by Microsoft for Windows 10, with the intent by Microsoft
to create the "ideal" trackpad experience (just quoting).

Here are the steps to follow.

**Check if you already have a Precision Touchpad**

Navigate to *Settings > Devices > Touchpad.* If you see the text
"Your PC has a precision touchpad", you’re already using a PC with a
Precision Touchpad, which means that these drivers are already installed,
so there is no point in continuing to the next section.

**Have a physical mouse ready**

Just In Case, ensure to have a physical mouse, in case you will lose
touchpad functionality after installing the Precision drivers.

You might also want to create a System Restore point, to be able to easily
revert to the old drivers if you need to.

**Uninstall the current driver**

If you have installed the Elan or Synaptics driver, uninstall it now.

In the Device Manager, right-click the touchpad, select *Uninstall*,
in the pop-up tick "Delete the driver software for this device" and press OK,
and finally reboot.

**Download the drivers**

Your driver is Elan, but I list here also Synaptics for other readers.

- Download Elan driver
  [from Softpedia](http://drivers.softpedia.com/get/Other-DRIVERS-TOOLS/Others/ELAN-Input-Device-for-WDF-Driver-161132-for-Windows-10-64-bit.shtml)
- Download Synaptics driver
  [from Lenovo](https://download.lenovo.com/pccbbs/mobiles/n1mgx14w.zip)

**Install the Precision drivers**

- Unzip to a temporary directory
- Start the Device Manager
- Under *Mice and other pointing devices*, right-click on the
  Elan (Synaptics) device
- Choose *Update driver*
- Click *Browse my computer for driver software*
- Select *Let me pick from a list of available drivers on my computer*
- Pick *Have Disk…*
- Choose *Browse…* and navigate to the above folder
- Select *Autorun.inf* in the folder
- Select the Elan device (or Synaptics) and click *Next*
- On the message *Update Driver Warning*, choose *Yes*
- Let the driver install
- Restart the computer

For a more detailed description of the installation with screenshots see
[How to enable a Precision Touchpad for more gestures on your laptop](https://www.windowscentral.com/how-enable-precision-touchpad-drivers).